# How to make multiple elements in a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to show multiple pipes in the canvas of same height but even after using a for loop it is showing a single pipe and not a lot of it

```
<script>
    var tryCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var c = tryCanvas.getContext("2d");
    var myCall = [];

    function Squares() {

        for(var i =0; i < 10; i++){
            this.x = Math.random()* tryCanvas.clientWidth;
            this.y = 0;
            this.w = 20;
            this.h = 60;
            this.counter = 0;
            this.draw = function() {
                c.beginPath();
                c.rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h)
                c.fill();
            }
    }

        this.update = function() {
            if(this.x < 0){
                this.x = 0;
            }
            this.x -= 1;
            this.draw();
        }
    }

    var holder = new Squares;

    setInterval(callFun, 10);

       function callFun() {
        c.clearRect(0,0,tryCanvas.clientWidth, tryCanvas.clientHeight);
        holder.update();    
       }
 </script>
```

If I push the constructor function in an array it's not showing anything in the canvas and in the console it's giving undefined or NaN.
But if I do it without "this" its generating the number of rects.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `c.clearRect(0,0,tryCanvas.clientWidth, tryCanvas.clientHeight);` does what?

Comment: it basically clears the canvas

Comment: Not just basically, it is practically cleared ...

Comment: yeah, but it should clear after going through the loop as in generating all the pipes and then clear them, or not? and if I don't use it the canvas is not cleared and the illusion of a single pipe is not achieved.

Comment: Within ten milliseconds ..?

Comment: @Teemu just using that for testing only, i know that's moving too fast

Comment: not defined as in?

Comment: Re-read Question, `draw` is defined, within `for` loop. What is expected result? What is issue with code at Question?

Comment: the expected result should be 10 pipes , the for loop is not working and its only generating a single pipe.

Comment: Why are you expecting ten different `canvas` elements?

Comment: that is the desired output, how do I make it happen? or what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Only one `<canvas>` element appears at JavaScript at Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated to move the bars along the screen**

See this working example:
https://codepen.io/bkfarns/pen/braWQB?editors=1010

This.draw will only get created with the values from the last iteration of the for loop.

Also as a side node, usually instead of `new Squares` you call the constructor like `new Squares()`.  When you call the constructor you are calling a method.

But I think the code below fixes your issues.  Try it out:

```
<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas"/>
</body>

<script>
    var tryCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var c = tryCanvas.getContext("2d");
    var myCall = [];

    function Squares() {

        this.draw = function(xOffset) {

          for(var i =0; i < 10; i++){

            this.x = (i * xOffset) + (5*i)//Math.random()* tryCanvas.clientWidth;
            this.y = 0;
            this.w = 20;
            this.h = 60;
            c.beginPath();
            c.rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h)
            c.fill();
          }
        }
    }

    var holder = new Squares();

    var xOffset = 20;
    setInterval(function() {
      c.clearRect(0,0,tryCanvas.clientWidth, tryCanvas.clientHeight);
      holder.draw(xOffset)
      xOffset--;
    }, 1000)


 </script>
```

Comment: What is the difference between `new Squares` and `new Squares()`?

Comment: I just tried it out in the console, and it does the same thing apparently. 
 But normally we always have parens there to pass arguments if necessary, just like a normal method. 
 See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: thanks a lot dude, this much I was able to do..but when I add an update function to make the pipes move along the x-axis that part is not working. 
 `this.update = function(){
            this.x -=1;
            this.draw();
        }`                                                                                                                               var holder = new Squares();
   
        setInterval(callFun, 10);

        function callFun() {
            holder.update();
        }
This part doesn't work.

Comment: I just updated my code example - I'm not sure if it is exactly what you are going for, but hopefully helps a little

Comment: thanks a lot man, your answer made it almost like I wanted :)